# c++ pathfinder - vector of objects with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, sfml, destructor, path-finding

I have a problem with destructor. I have two classes: Map and Tile. They looks like that:
(if code fragments below are not enough i'm adding github with this project with full code inside:
https://github.com/TMalicki/PathFinder-algorithms)

```
class Tile
{
  private:
  Tile* parent;
  ...
  public:
  Tile(sf::Vector2f size = { 50.f ,50.f });
  Tile(const Tile& cTile);
  Tile& operator=(const Tile& aTile);
  ~Tile();
  ...
}
```

and

```
class Map
{
private:
vector<Tile*> board;
...
public:   
Map(sf::Vector2i numberOfTiles = { 10, 10 }, sf::Vector2f sizeOfTiles = { 
50.f, 50.f });
Map(const Map& cMap);
Map& operator=(const Map& aMap);
~Map();
...
}
```

They destructors looks like that:

```
Tile::~Tile()
{
    if (parent != nullptr)
    {
        delete parent;
        parent = nullptr;
    }
}

Map::~Map()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++)
    {
        delete board[i];
        board[i] = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Code is used for shortest path search algorithm. I have to store previous Tile so when algorithm find finish it can search backwards shortest path. I can add some more code if it;s needed. To sum up: Map object has vector of Tiles. And every Tile firstly is not pointing anything. But if it's used by algorithm than this exact Tile store position of previous one, and so on to the beginning. I know propably smart pointers can help me but i though it would be good for me to learn firstly how to do this maybe harder way.
I think that the problem is that (i don;t exactly know why) while deleting Map vector with Tiles i do not only delete exact Tile, but also somehow Tile who is parent of that Tile? And f.e. in the next iteration when it should delete that parent of previous iteration it cannot because it is already delete. I thought that after if statement inside Tile destructor it wont be delated if it already is. But it's not helping.

I've got exception thrown like that:

[image]

And from debugger mode i have this:

- first iteration
  [image]
- second iteration
  [image]

During analisation from debugger mode i've start thinking that destructor of exact tile delete firstly parent tile, and than himself. And after that it jumps to line parent = nullptr inside Tile destructor. But somehow only child Tile is being set to nullptr.

Comment: `Map object has vector of Tiles.` -- No it doesn't.  It has a vector of `Tile *`, not `Tile`.  Why is it not simply `vector<Tile>`?  And if pointers are shared between objects, there is something in C++ called `std::shared_ptr` instead of using raw pointers.

Comment: #PaulMcKenzie Yeah i know about smart pointers, but i thought that it helps me to better understand that topic. So i tried to avoid smart pointers in that project. Also ... yeah, i mean `Tile*`. And i used `Tile*` because i would like to change some attributes of `Tile` objects from `Map` class object.

Comment: You are deleting `Tile *` all over the place without a coherent strategy of who is the owner.  You are deleting `Tile *` in the Map destructor, but also deleting `Tile *` in the Tile destructor (the parent).  Who owns what?  You can't delete the same memory address twice.  That is exactly what the problem a shared pointer solves -- if you know that two or more entities will share a pointer, and the last one to use it is the last one to `delete` the pointer, then that is what a shared_ptr is used for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely that parent is not an owning pointer so it should not delete the parent.

```
Tile::~Tile() {
    if (parent != nullptr) {
        delete parent; <----------- here
        parent = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Otherwise when Map delete the tile, it has already been deleted. Removing this part of the code should solve the problem.

Comment: #Surt can you explain that more detailed? What do you mean with parent not owning pointer? But parent is pointer. Somehow i feel that i know that it is correct answer but i don;t think that i understand that fully. I fixed that in your way and now it's working but still i will appreciate some better tips why that;s wrong. Is it because `Map` class has `vector<Tile*>? I'm thinking that in `Map` destructor i delete whole `Tile`, but `Tile` class has pointer which supposed to be destroyed in `Tile` class...

Comment: @Tojmak If I understand your code correctly then Map owns all the tiles, the parent in Tile is only another Tile already owned by Map.

Comment: That's true. Okay... something clicked ;d. So... to sum up. parent is in fact attribute of Tile class. And it should be delete. But as it point another Tile than it should be delete where all Tiles are deleted. So... inside Map class, in that line `delete board[i];`. That line delete Tile object, but before that destructor of Tile class was executed. And what i did before was delete another Tile (which will be still deleted by Map destructor) with parent pointing on that Tile. Is that true? ;d

Comment: @Tojmak yes, you did a double delete of the Tiles.